# jQuery DOM traversal without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to place a `div`, traversing upwards in DOM, with a click event using jQuery's `.insertAfter()` method. Everything works fine except that the page is reloading when the event fires.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar_menu_resp_gift a').click(function(event) {
    $('.sidebar').insertAfter('.sidebar_menu_resp_gift');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar .side_box_1').slideToggle();
  });
  $('.sidebar_menu_resp_occassion a').click(function(event) {
    $('.sidebar').insertAfter('.sidebar_menu_resp_occassion');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar .side_box_2').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar_menu_resp_gift">
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar_menu_resp_occassion">
    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="side_box_1">
      <ul>
        <li>something 1</li>
        <li>something 2</li>
        <li>something 3</li>
        <li>something 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="side_box_2">
      <ul>
        <li>something 5</li>
        <li>something 6</li>
        <li>something 7</li>
        <li>something 8</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I actually want to achieve is when clicking on (`.sidebar_menu_resp_gift a`) must instantly slide down (`.side_box_1`) below it pushing everything beneath down. and same in the case of (`.sidebar_menu_resp_occassion a`) also, (`.side_box_2`) must drop down below it. But I side_box div's dropsdown where it actually was in HTML. So I decided to use `.insertAfter()`. But it reloads the page on click event. Any wayout guyz?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use .live() or .on() instead of .click();

Comment: .live() is deprecated as of JQuery 1.7. However .on() is not

Comment: $('document').on("click",".sidebar_menu_resp_occassion a", function(event){
return false; //At the end
})

Answer (score 0):

I would have written it something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidebar_menu_resp_gift').on('click','a',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
    $('.sidebar_menu_resp_occassion').on('click','a',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar_menu_resp_gift">
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <div class="side_box_1">
        <ul>
            <li>something 1</li>
            <li>something 2</li>
            <li>something 3</li>
            <li>something 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_menu_resp_occassion">
    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <div class="side_box_2">
        <ul>
            <li>something 5</li>
            <li>something 6</li>
            <li>something 7</li>
            <li>something 8</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```